# How to compare subtract one date from another and get days?

Tags: javascript, datetime

```
function createDate(d) {
   var year = parseFloat(d.substring(6, 10)); 
   var month = parseFloat(d.substring(0,2)); 
   var day = parseFloat(d.substring(3, 5)); 

   var d = new Date(year, month, day); 

   return d; 
}

var d1 = $("#DateCarArrival").val();
var d2 = $("#DateCarLeaving").val(); 

var date1 = createDate(d1); 
var date2 = createDate(d2);

console.log(date1.toString()); 
console.log(date2.toString());   

//       Mon Feb 18 2013 13:19:26 GMT+0100
//      Mon Feb 18 2013 13:19:26 GMT+0100
```

How to compare these dates and get the number of days they are in between?

Comment: `d.getFullYear(year, month, day);` It can't work fine. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear), `getFullYear` doesn't have arguments.

Comment: @VisioN `getFillYear` or `getFullYear` ? O.o

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**NOTE:** this answer is assuming a STRING of `mm/dd/yyyy`
If you use `type="date"` in Chrome, you will get strings of `yyyy-dd-mm`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/44s2Y/)

```
function createDate(d) {
   var year = parseInt(d.substring(6, 10),10); 
   var month = parseInt(d.substring(0,2),10); 
   var day = parseInt(d.substring(3, 5),10); 

   var d = new Date(year, month-1, day); // JS Months are 0 based
   return d; 
}

var d1 = $("#DateCarArrival").val();
var d2 = $("#DateCarLeaving").val(); 

var date1 = createDate(d1); 
var date2 = createDate(d2);

var aDay = 24*60*60*1000;
var diff = Math.abs((date1.getTime()-date2.getTime())/aDay)
console.log(date1.toString(),date2.toString(),diff);
```

Comment: Thanks. I am creating a jsfiddle - I am worried about input type=date

Answer (score 2):

convert date to milliseconds(using `valueOf()`) and then substract

```
DifferNumDays = (date1.valueOf() - date2.valueOf())/(24*60*60*1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the difference (in days) and compare two dates, you can use these prototype extender methods:

*Note: I've distributed the logic into multiple methods that can be used (as helpers) in many different scenarios.*

```
/** Gets the type (name) of the specified object. 
 */
if (!Object.prototype.getType) {
    Object.prototype.getType = function (obj) {
        return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-z|A-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
    }
}

/** Checks whether the object is Date. 
 */
if (!Object.prototype.isDate) {
    Object.prototype.isDate = function (date) {
        return Object.getType(date) === 'date';
    }
}

/** Gets the difference in days, between the given dates. 
 *  If an invalid date is passed as a parameter, returns null.
 */
if (!Date.prototype.difference) {
    Date.prototype.difference = function (date1, date2) {
        if (!(Object.isDate(date1) && Object.isDate(date2))) return null;
        var diff = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime()),
            msInOneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        return Math.round(diff / msInOneDay);
    }
}

/** Compares the date instance to the specified date value and returns an integer that indicates whether 
 *  the instance is earlier than, the same as, or later than the specified date value. 
 *  @return -1 if the specified date is invalid. 0 if they are the same. 1 if date1 is greater. 2 if date2 is greater.
 */
if (!Date.prototype.compareTo) {
    Date.prototype.compareTo = function (date) {
        if (!Object.isDate(date)) return -1; //not a Date
        if (this == date) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this > date) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 2; //date > this
        } 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
//Validate a date object
var dateIsValid = Object.isDate(date1);
//get the difference in days
var numOfDaysBetween = Date.difference(date1, date2);
//compare date to another
var comparison = date1.compareTo(date2);
```

Answer (score -2):

You could convert the dates to milliseconds with [getMilliseconds()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp), subtract them and count it from milliseconds.

Comment: The getMilliseconds() method returns the milliseconds (from 0 to 999) of the specified date and time.